# Closed form solution for the series $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, geometric-series, telescopic-series

I'd like to start by thanking you for your time reading this question and your passion for mathematics.

It would be a pleasant surprise to me if there were a closed form expression for the sum:

$$\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n+1}$$

Knowing well that it converges, as term by term, $\frac{1}{2^n+1}<\frac{1}{2^n}$, I searched for a taylor series expansion, I rewrote the expression as $\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^n \cdot (2^n+1)}=\frac {2^{-n}}{1+2^{-n}}=1-\frac {1}{1+2^{-n}}$ in hopes of something, telescoping, nth partial-sum-exposing, or otherwise, all to no avail.

So I ask more accomplished and brilliant minds their thoughts.   Thank goodness for MSE.

Comment: Actually I don't have so much time to carefully analyse your series. My 1st idea is to look for the Riemann sum of some (i don't know yet which) integral. This would be a finite sum, say from 1 to n. Then pass with $n$ to infinity.

Comment: A closed form for this series involves the digamma function.

Comment: So far I would need to familiarize myself with Fourier Expansions and Gamma Functions

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html

Comment: There isn't going to be any simple solution.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt suspected so, I was just surprised that I couldn't find anything on this series anywhere when I searched for one